# Save the output of for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to manipulate the output from the following "for loop":

```
for i in $patch_set;do
     key= 201508 #see the comments after the code
     csvArr[$key]=$strings
done
for roF in $(echo -e $autopatch)
do
filename=`basename $roF`
    key=201508 #see the comments after the code
    echo -e "$key ${csvArr[$key]}"
done
```

where in:

1. `$patch_set` is storred couple of file names like `patch.dot`, `patch2.dot`, `patch3.dot` and so on.
2. Every `patch*.dot` file has string content in it
3. `$key` is changing from time to time - it can be changed to `201509` or some equivalent date. I made just made it static in the code.
4. `$string` is the content of `patch*.dot` files
5. `$autopatch` is filled with paths like this:

   - `/backend/dot/scipts/shock/201508/SQL/file.sql`
   - `/backend/dot/scipts/shock/201509/SQL/file.sql`

The idea of the code is to grab the content in `patch*.dot` files, which content is a text. Is there a way to store the output in some variable in order to read and edit it?

Comment: To store the output of a command in a variable, you do `var=$(command)`. Is that what you're asking? Isn't this basic shell scripting knowledge?

Comment: Or you can use backticks, like you did in the line that assigns `filename`.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the entire script inside `$(...)` to capture its output into a variable.

```
var=$(
    for i in $patch_set;do
         key=201508
         csvArr[$key]=$strings
    done
    for roF in $(echo -e $autopatch)
    do
    filename=`basename $roF`
        key=201508
        echo -e "$key ${csvArr[$key]}"
    done)
```